# Resume Azure VM backup using powershell script after disabling backup

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-backup-vault

I would like to resume my backup after disabling backup.
Used the below commands for disabling and enabling.
Disabling backup :**Disable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -Item $backupItems -Force**
Enabling backup : **Enable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection**

Now if I run **Enable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection** command then I am getting the error. My use case is I want to check RSV exist or not and if RSV is not exist then I should create new RSV,new policy,enable the policy and run the backup and disabling the backup using the above command. Now,if I run the same script again and since RSV is created already along with policy now and here I want to resume my backup only(When I first run my script I have disabled my backup).Only for that I am not able to find any powershell command.If I run the command **Enable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection** then its failing with the below error.So please help me to understand how to handle this using powershell script. The entire steps have been done through powershell script.

**Error:**

##[error]Item is not protected. Please check if item is associated with any policy.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

Also, my powershell script should handle the below scenario.

Requirement for Production env: My powershell script should only run the backup using already existing policy which might be different than the policy which I declared in powershell script and which have already backup running. So here I should only run backup in prod environment regardless of which policy its using.How to handle this scenario?

**VMBACKUP.ps1**

```
####################### Parameters for the VM Backup Process #######################
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][String]$ResourceGroupName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][String]$SourceVMname,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][String]$RSVaultname,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][String]$PolicyName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][String]$Location,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][String]$Storagetype,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][String]$WorkLoadType
)

####################### Connecting to Azure via Service principal and install the AZ modules #######################
Write-Host "Check for AZ modules and install the AZ modules if not available"
if (-not(Get-Module -Name Az.Accounts -ListAvailable)) {
    Write-Warning "Module 'Az.Accounts' is missing or out of date. Installing module now."
    Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts, Az.Resources, Az.Automation, Az.RecoveryServices -Scope CurrentUser -Force -AllowClobber
}

####################### Registering the Azure Recovery Service provider in the subscription #######################

Write-Host "Registering the Azure Recovery Service provider in the subscription"
try {
    Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace "Microsoft.RecoveryServices" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
catch {
    $message = $_
    Write-Warning "An error occurred! $message"
}

#######################  Check if RSV is exist,create if not exist already and setup vault context ####################### 
Write-Host "Check if RSV is exist,create if not exist already and setup vault context"
$targetVault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $RSVaultname -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$targetVault.ID

####################### Setting up VaultContext using Vault and Setting up Storage redundancy #######################
Write-Host "Setting up VaultContext using Vault and Setting up Storage redundancy"
$e = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"
try {
    Set-AzRecoveryServicesVaultContext -Vault $targetVault -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Set-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProperty -Vault $targetVault -BackupStorageRedundancy $Storagetype -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
catch {
    $ErrorActionPreference = $e
}
$ErrorActionPreference = $e;


####################### Fetching the right container and backup items #######################
Write-Host "Fetching the right container and backup items"
$e = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"
try {
    $backupcontainer = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType $WorkLoadType -FriendlyName $SourceVMname -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $item = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $backupcontainer -WorkloadType $WorkLoadType -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
catch {
    $ErrorActionPreference = $e
}

$ErrorActionPreference = $e;

####################### Check if RSV is exist already,if exist then go to else block ###############
Write-Host "Checking if RSV already exist"
if ($notPresent) {
    New-AzRecoveryServicesVault -Name $RSVaultname -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location
    
    ####################### Fetching vault resource values #######################
    Write-Host "Fetching vault resource values"
    $targetVault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $RSVaultname
    $targetVault.ID

    ####################### Setting up VaultContext using Vault and Setting up Storage redundancy #######################
    Write-Host "Setting up VaultContext using Vault and Setting up Storage redundancy"
    Set-AzRecoveryServicesVaultContext -Vault $targetVault
    Set-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProperty -Vault $targetVault -BackupStorageRedundancy $Storagetype
   
    ####################### Setting up new backup policy #######################
    Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Name $PolicyName -VaultId $targetVault.ID -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($notPresent) {
        Write-Host "Setting up a new valid Backup Policy"
        $schPol = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupSchedulePolicyObject -WorkloadType $WorkLoadType
        $UtcTime = Get-Date -Date 0001-01-01T00:00:00 #This is the time that you want to start the backup
        $UtcTime = $UtcTime.ToUniversalTime()
        $schpol.ScheduleRunTimes[0] = $UtcTime
        $retPol = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupRetentionPolicyObject -WorkloadType $WorkLoadType
        New-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Name $PolicyName -WorkloadType $WorkLoadType -RetentionPolicy $retPol -SchedulePolicy $schPol -VaultId $targetVault.ID
    }
    $pol = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Name $PolicyName -VaultId $targetVault.ID
    $pol

    ####################### Enable Backup protection in the new Policy #######################
    Write-host "Enable Backup protection in the $PolicyName"
    try {
   
        Enable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $SourceVMname -Policy $pol -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    catch {
        $message = $_
        Write-Warning "An error occurred! $message"
    }

    ####################### Fetching the right container and backup items #######################
    $backupcontainer = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType $WorkLoadType -FriendlyName $SourceVMname -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $item = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $backupcontainer -WorkloadType $WorkLoadType -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    ###################### Calling backup script #######################
    Invoke-Expression "$PSScriptRoot\createbackup.ps1"

    ####################### Disable backup protection in the RSV #######################
    Write-Host "Disable backup protection in the RSV"
    try {
        $containers = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType $WorkLoadType -FriendlyName $SourceVMname
        $backupItems = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $containers[0] -WorkloadType $WorkLoadType
        # Disble the backup protection in RSV to delete backup items
        Disable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -Item $backupItems -Force
        Write-Host "Backup is successfully disabled"
    }
    catch {
        $message = $_
        Write-Warning "An error occured! $message"
    }
}
###################### RSV is already exist,run backup script #####################                  }
else {
    
    Invoke-Expression "$PSScriptRoot\createbackup.ps1"
}
```

**CREATEBACKUP.ps1**

```
####################### Backup process starts now ##########################
####################### Checking the status of backup jobs and wait until its configuring the backup #######################
Write-Host "Checking the status of Configure backup jobs and wait until its configuring the backup"
$ConfigureBackup = Get-AzRecoveryservicesBackupJob
while ($ConfigureBackup.Status -eq "In progress") {
   start-sleep -s 30
   write-host "Configure Backup is still in progress"
}

####################### Backup process begins #######################
Write-Host "Backup process begins"
$backupjob = Backup-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Item $item
$backupjob
start-sleep -s 60

####################### Fail the pipeline if backup is failed #######################

if ($backupjob.Status -eq "Failed") {
   throw "Backup is failed"
}

####################### Get the Backup Status #######################
Write-Host "Current Backup Status"
Get-AzRecoveryservicesBackupJob

####################### Look for the backup subtask: Take Snapshot in RSV for Backup job and wait for it to complete #######################
Write-Host "Look for the backup subtask: Take Snapshot in RSV for Backup job and wait for it to complete"
$Jobs = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupJob -Status InProgress -VaultId $targetVault.ID
$JobId = $Jobs[0].JobId
DO {
   $subtasks = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupJobDetail -JobId $JobId -VaultId $targetVault.ID
   $subtask = $subtasks.SubTasks | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Take Snapshot" }
   $subtask.Status
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
}UNTIL ($subtask.Status -eq "Completed")

####################### Fail the pipeline if backup is failed #######################
try { 
   if ($backupjob.Status -eq "Failed") {   
      throw "Backup is failed"
   }
}
catch {
   $message = $_
   Write-Warning "An error occurred! $message"
}
start-sleep -s 30
####################### Here is the final backup status #######################
Write-Host "Here is the final backup status"
Get-AzRecoveryservicesBackupJob
Write-Output "Backup process is completed successfully"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue and able to get successful backup for multiple scenarios.

```
**vmbackup.ps1:**
    ####################### Parameters for the VM Backup Process #######################
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][String]$ResourceGroupName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][String]$SourceVMname,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][String]$RSVaultname,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][String]$PolicyName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][String]$Location,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][String]$Storagetype,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][String]$WorkLoadType,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][String]$PolicyName2
    )
    
    ####################### Connecting to Azure via Service principal and install the AZ modules #######################
    Write-Host "Check for AZ modules and install the AZ modules if not available"
    if (-not(Get-Module -Name Az.Accounts -ListAvailable)) {
        Write-Warning "Module 'Az.Accounts' is missing or out of date. Installing module now."
        Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts, Az.Resources, Az.Automation, Az.RecoveryServices -Scope CurrentUser -Force -AllowClobber
    }
    
    ####################### Registering the Azure Recovery Service provider in the subscription #######################
    
    Write-Host "Registering the Azure Recovery Service provider in the subscription"
    try {
        Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace "Microsoft.RecoveryServices" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    catch {
        $message = $_
        Write-Warning "An error occurred! $message"
    }
    
    #######################  Check if RSV is exist,create if not exist already and setup vault context ####################### 
    Write-Host "Check if RSV is exist,create if not exist already and setup vault context"
    $targetVault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $RSVaultname -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $targetVault.ID
    
    ####################### Setting up VaultContext using Vault and Setting up Storage redundancy #######################
    Write-Host "Setting up VaultContext using Vault and Setting up Storage redundancy"
    $e = $ErrorActionPreference
    $ErrorActionPreference = "stop"
    try {
        Set-AzRecoveryServicesVaultContext -Vault $targetVault -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Set-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProperty -Vault $targetVault -BackupStorageRedundancy $Storagetype -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    catch {
        $ErrorActionPreference = $e
    }
    $ErrorActionPreference = $e;
    
    
    ####################### Fetching the right container and backup items #######################
    Write-Host "Fetching the right container and backup items"
    $e = $ErrorActionPreference
    $ErrorActionPreference = "stop"
    try {
        $backupcontainer = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType $WorkLoadType -FriendlyName $SourceVMname -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $item = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $backupcontainer -WorkloadType $WorkLoadType -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    catch {
        $ErrorActionPreference = $e
    }
    
    $ErrorActionPreference = $e;
    
    ####################### Check if RSV is exist already,if exist then go to else block ###############
    Write-Host "Checking if RSV already exist"
    if ($notPresent) {
        New-AzRecoveryServicesVault -Name $RSVaultname -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location
        
        ####################### Fetching vault resource values #######################
        Write-Host "Fetching vault resource values"
        $targetVault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $RSVaultname
        $targetVault.ID
    
        ####################### Setting up VaultContext using Vault and Setting up Storage redundancy #######################
        Write-Host "Setting up VaultContext using Vault and Setting up Storage redundancy"
        Set-AzRecoveryServicesVaultContext -Vault $targetVault
        Set-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProperty -Vault $targetVault -BackupStorageRedundancy $Storagetype
       
        ####################### Setting up new backup policy #######################
        Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Name $PolicyName -VaultId $targetVault.ID -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Name $PolicyName2 -VaultId $targetVault.ID -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($notPresent) {
            Write-Host "Setting up a new valid Backup Policy"
            $schPol = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupSchedulePolicyObject -WorkloadType $WorkLoadType
            $UtcTime = Get-Date -Date 0001-01-01T00:00:00 #This is the time that you want to start the backup
            $UtcTime = $UtcTime.ToUniversalTime()
            $schpol.ScheduleRunTimes[0] = $UtcTime
            $retPol = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupRetentionPolicyObject -WorkloadType $WorkLoadType
            New-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Name $PolicyName -WorkloadType $WorkLoadType -RetentionPolicy $retPol -SchedulePolicy $schPol -VaultId $targetVault.ID
        }
        $pol = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Name $PolicyName -VaultId $targetVault.ID
        $pol
    
        ####################### Enable Backup protection in the new Policy #######################
        Write-host "Enable Backup protection in the $PolicyName"
        try {
       
            Enable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $SourceVMname -Policy $pol -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
        catch {
            $message = $_
            Write-Warning "An error occurred! $message"
        }
    
        ####################### Fetching the right container and backup items #######################
        $backupcontainer = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType $WorkLoadType -FriendlyName $SourceVMname -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $item = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $backupcontainer -WorkloadType $WorkLoadType -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    
        ###################### Calling backup script #######################
        #$present=0
        Invoke-Expression "$PSScriptRoot\createbackup.ps1"
    
        ####################### Disable backup protection in the RSV #######################
        Write-Host "Disable backup protection in the RSV"
        try {
            $containers = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType $WorkLoadType -FriendlyName $SourceVMname
            $backupItems = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $containers[0] -WorkloadType $WorkLoadType
            # Disble the backup protection in RSV to delete backup items
            Disable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -Item $backupItems -Force
            Write-Host "Backup is successfully disabled"
        }
        catch {
            $message = $_
            Write-Warning "An error occured! $message"
        }
    }
    ###################### RSV is already exist,run backup script #####################                  }
    else {
        #$present=1
        Invoke-Expression "$PSScriptRoot\createbackup.ps1"
    }
```

**Createbackup.ps1:**

```
####################### Changing the backup policy to enable backup again if disabled ##########################
Write-Host "Check VM backup status"
$status = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupStatus -Name $SourceVMname -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Type "AzureVM"
        If ($status.VaultId) {
            $rsv = $status.VaultId.Split('/')[-1]    
            Write-Output "The VM < $SourceVMname > is member of RSV < $rsv >"    
            $Disablestatus1 = Get-AzRecoveryservicesBackupJob
            Write-Host "Overall jobs status"
            $Disablestatus1
            Write-Host "Initial job status"
            $Disablestatus1[0]
            if (($Disablestatus1[0].Operation -eq "Disablebackup") -and ($Disablestatus1[0].Status -eq "Completed")) {
            $Disablestatus2 = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupJob -VaultId $targetVault.ID -Operation Disablebackup
            Write-Host "Overall disable jobs backup status"
            $Disablestatus2
            Write-Host "disable initial backup status"
            $Disablestatus2[0]
        
        If ($Disablestatus2.Status -eq "Completed") {
            Write-Output "The VM < $SourceVMname > is not protected with Azure Backup. You should consider enabling it!" 
            Write-Host "Changing the backup policy to resume backup again since its disabled in the last run"
            $schPol = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupSchedulePolicyObject -WorkloadType $WorkLoadType
            $UtcTime = Get-Date -Date 0001-01-02T00:00:00 #This is the time that you want to start the backup
            $UtcTime = $UtcTime.ToUniversalTime()
            $schpol.ScheduleRunTimes[0] = $UtcTime
            $retPol = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupRetentionPolicyObject -WorkloadType $WorkLoadType
            New-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Name $PolicyName2 -WorkloadType $WorkLoadType -RetentionPolicy $retPol -SchedulePolicy $schPol -VaultId $targetVault.ID
            $targetVault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $RSVaultname
            $TargetPol1 = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Name $PolicyName2 -VaultId $targetVault.ID
            $anotherBkpItem = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -WorkloadType $WorkLoadType -BackupManagementType $WorkLoadType -Name $SourceVMname -VaultId $targetVault.ID
            Enable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -Item $anotherBkpItem -Policy $TargetPol1 -VaultId $targetVault.ID
        }
      }}
####################### Actual Backup process starts now ##########################
####################### Checking the status of backup jobs and wait until its configuring the backup #######################
Write-Host "Checking the status of Configure backup jobs and wait until its configuring the backup"
$ConfigureBackup = Get-AzRecoveryservicesBackupJob
while ($ConfigureBackup.Status -eq "In progress") {
   start-sleep -s 30
   write-host "Configure Backup is still in progress"
}

####################### Backup process begins #######################
Write-Host "Actual Backup process begins"
$backupjob = Backup-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Item $item
$backupjob
start-sleep -s 60

####################### Fail the pipeline if backup is failed #######################

if ($backupjob.Status -eq "Failed") {
   throw "Backup is failed"
}

####################### Get the Backup Status #######################
Write-Host "Current Backup Status"
Get-AzRecoveryservicesBackupJob

####################### Look for the backup subtask: Take Snapshot in RSV for Backup job and wait for it to complete #######################
Write-Host "Look for the backup subtask: Take Snapshot in RSV for Backup job and wait for it to complete"
$Jobs = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupJob -Status InProgress -VaultId $targetVault.ID
$JobId = $Jobs[0].JobId
DO {
   $subtasks = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupJobDetail -JobId $JobId -VaultId $targetVault.ID
   $subtask = $subtasks.SubTasks | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Take Snapshot" }
   $subtask.Status
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
}UNTIL ($subtask.Status -eq "Completed")

####################### Fail the pipeline if backup is failed #######################
try { 
   if ($backupjob.Status -eq "Failed") {   
      throw "Backup is failed"
   }
}
catch {
   $message = $_
   Write-Warning "An error occurred! $message"
}
start-sleep -s 30
####################### Here is the final backup status #######################
Write-Host "Here is the final backup status"
Get-AzRecoveryservicesBackupJob
Write-Output "Backup process is completed successfully"
```